# Titanium ScrollView Doesn't Grow When TableViewRow is Added

Tags: ios, titanium, scrollview, tableview, appcelerator

I have a scrollview that is defined as follows:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    contentHeight: 'auto', 
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
    layout: 'vertical'
});
```

and at the bottom of the scrollview, I have a tableview. The user can press a button to insert a new row at the top of the tableview. However, when they do this, the scrollview's content area doesn't grow and therefore, the first row (at the bottom of the tableview) doesn't show anymore. Each time the user add's a new row, the oldest one on the bottom doesn't show anymore.

If I were explicitly setting the contentHeight, then I could just add the size of the row each time the user added a new row. I would prefer not to do this though.

Is there any way to automatically grow the scrollview to fit it's children, including new tableview rows?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an older version of titanium, you can use postLayout callback to update the height appropriately

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/#!/guide/Transitioning_to_the_New_UI_Layout_System-section-30088148_TransitioningtotheNewUILayoutSystem-BatchLayoutUpdates

if you are using a more recent release then you should review this documentation. Specifically regard Batch Layout Updates and the use of applyProperties call on view objects

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Transitioning_to_the_New_UI_Layout_System

Answer (score 0):

What is the height of the tableview? I don't think the tableview "grows" with the insertion of a new row. It stays the same size, but you can scroll its content. Just for a test, try logging the height of your tableview before and after adding the row.

Also, as you may know, it's not the best to have a scrollable item as the tableview inside another scrollable item.

Comment: The height of my tableview is not set, which means it should be automatic. The tableview also doesn't scroll, I agree that it would be bad to have a scrollable element inside another scrollable element. I have found a temporary solution of calling appendRow on the very last row after all rows have been added (basically adding the last row twice) and that seems to work. Although it is a hacky solution.

Comment: Still, if the tableview is expanding, the scrollview should fits it. In a project I have different views added to a scrollview and it grows automatically, but I didn't set the `contentHeight` property. You can try leaving that out. Also, in addition to the tableview height, you can log the contentHeight of the scrollview before and after adding the row. Just to be sure everything's as expected.

Comment: That's the thing, if I add other views to the scrollview, it expands. If I used the appendRow method instead of tableview.data = data, it expands. For some reason, setting the tableview data doesn't cause the tableview to recalculate its height.

Comment: Ok. If `appendRow` expands the tableview, you can probably use `insertRowBefore` ([Ti docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-insertRowBefore)). You should be able to add your new row first, and it *should* expand the tableview.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I use insertRowBefore (with a nice little animation) and unfortunately, it pushes the bottom most row out of the scrollView content area. That is why I then have to figure out what was in that bottom most row and call appendRow on it, which seems to extend the scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

The tableview does grow to fit its children. However, if you set the tableview data like

```
tableView.data = data;
```

It does not recalculate the height. Rather, you must remove all rows and use the `appendRow` method or if you only need to add on a row to the end of the table (not the beginning), you can just use the `appendRow` method without first deleting all rows.